# SSIS connection expression problem

Tags: ssis

Im trying to use an expression to a sub package in SSIS however it always errors out stating that it cannot find the dtsx file.  Ive copied the path to explorer and it seems to be correct.

The error also states that expression cannot be written to the property.  My code is below.

@[User::vRoot] + "\Employees.dtsx" with @[User::vRoot] being a variable stored in SQL

Any Ideas

Answer (score 2):

Try to escape the backslash in the expression using an additional backslash.

```
@[User::vRoot] + "\\Employees.dtsx"
```

In such a scenario where I need to concatenate folder and file name, I always do it this way. I usually create two variables named `FolderPath` and `FileName`. Let's assume *FolderPath* contains `C:\temp\` (**make sure it ends with a back slash**)  and *FileName* contains `Employees.dtsx`.

I will create a third variable named `FilePath` and will set the *EvaluateAsExpression* property of this variable to *true*. I will set the following expression in this variable so it dynamically evaluates the value.

```
@[User::FolderPath] + @[User::FileName]
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Backslash is an escape character here, so if you want to represent a literal backslash, it's "\\".

I also suggest, as a general rule, instead of hardcoding a backslash in the string concatenation, to use this method to consider potential trailing backslashes in the first variable:

@[User::vRoot] + (RIGHT(@[User::vRoot], 1) == "\\" ? "" : "\\") + "Employees.dtsx"